# How to fix the arrow button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to fix the `arrow button` which I attached I'm using the `http://jsfiddle.net/shpoont/3cA4x/` codes.
I cannot change the Html codes, they are generate by a program. I can Only override the CSS codes.
Thanks for your help.
The short list of the button code is given below:

```
<button id="flowSelectUsersBtn" class="btn btn-progress progress-active" href="#">
    <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Select Users</span>
</button>

[![arrow button][1]][1]
```

Here are the CSS codes:

```
.progress-active {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;

}
.progress-active {
    padding-left: 36px;
}

.progress-active:before,
.progress-active:after { 
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px; 
    width: 22px; 
    height: 22px; 
    background: inherit; 
    border: inherit; 
    border-left-color: transparent; 
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 0px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
}
.progress-active:before,
.progress-active:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.progress-active:before{ 
    left: -11px;
}
.progress-active:after { 
    right: -11px;
}
.progress-active:after { 
    z-index: 1;
}
.progress-active:before { 
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Could you put the code into  a snippet instead? It will be easier to picture what you currently have

Comment: what exactly do you want to change here?

Comment: like amit said, what do you want to change? If you have access to the CSS, you would basically be able to change anything in terms of visuals

Comment: I added the image.Thanks

Comment: The head of the arrow is not adjusted correctly(width is shorter). it has to be fit to the width of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
    .progress-active {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 18px;
        padding-right: 18px;
        border: none;

    }
    .progress-active {
        padding-left: 36px;
    }

    .progress-active:before,
    .progress-active:after { 
        content:"";
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px; 
        width: 13px; 
        height: 13px; 
        background: inherit;  
        
    }
    .progress-active:before,
    .progress-active:after {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    .progress-active:before{ 
        left: -5px;
    }
    .progress-active:after { 
        right: -5px;
    }
    .progress-active:after { 
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .progress-active:before { 
        background-color: white;
    }
```

```html
<button id="flowSelectUsersBtn" class="btn btn-progress progress-active" href="#">
                  <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Select Users</span>
                  </button>
                  <button id="flowSelectUsersBtn" class="btn btn-progress progress-active" href="#">
                  <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Select Users</span>
                  </button>
                  <button id="flowSelectUsersBtn" class="btn btn-progress progress-active" href="#">
                  <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Select Users</span>
                  </button>
```

Comment: When I Run code snippet looks good but in my page does not look good the arrow height is very small and does not cover the whole part of the button on the right. How can I increase the height of the arrows?  by default, the height button is bigger and my code will override the original code so the height arrow should be bigger. thanks.

Comment: .progress-active:before,
    .progress-active:after { 
        content:"";
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px; 
        width: 13px; 
        height: 13px; 
        background: inherit;  
    }
here adjust top, width and height..
.progress-active:before{ 
        left: -5px;
    }
    .progress-active:after { 
        right: -5px;
    }
then adjust here left and right.